# Normalization error when looping data in .txt

Tags: python, nlp

I am doing the normalization on a data saved in text format file (.TXT)
The code is as below:

```py
with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/mly.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f: 
     mylist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
     for f in mylist:
         a =  normalizer.normalize(f, assume_wrong=False)
```

The error is:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent calllast) <ipython-input-277-6be23a591fef> in <module>
       1 for f in mylist:
 ----> 2     a =  normalizer.normalize(f, assume_wrong = False)

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\malaya\normalize.py in normalize(self,
 string, assume_wrong, check_english)
     544                 continue
     545             selected = self._speller.correct(
 --> 546                 word, debug = False, assume_wrong = assume_wrong
     547             )
     548             result.append(result_string + selected + nd_result_string)

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\malaya\spell.py in correct(self, word,
 fast, **kwargs)
     296             else:
     297                 word = max(
 --> 298                     self.edit_candidates(word, fast = fast), key = self.P
     299                 )
     300         if len(hujung_result) and not word.endswith(hujung_result):

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what is the normalizer object? Whatever it is, I guess the problem might be, you pass in an empty string.

Comment: what do you mean by normalizer object? Im normalizing the text. Is this answered your question?

Comment: Jindrich means: your problem is with the normalizer object and the normalize method. We don't know which object is this and cannot help you unless you provide us some code to see what is going on. It seems you're using a tool that is not popular (probably you yourself made this package?)